# Save BIOS settings and make a backup

Tags: windows, boot

I want to save the BIOS settings and make these settings the default version of the BIOS in the gigabyte motherboard

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For gigabyte motherboard you might be able to use the
[Q-Flash utility](https://www.gigabyte.com/MicroSite/121/tech_qflash.htm),
which is said to be able to save and load OC profiles from disk.

I have never used this utility, so cannot say how well it works.

Even if it works for your purpose,
note that you should only use it between computers having the same
BIOS version.

Moving settings between different BIOS version might be dangerous.

Comment: I have already used Q-FLASH utility but saved as a file in hard disk. What I want is to make the backup the default for the bios

Comment: You may need to mod the BIOS itself, which requires lots of knowledge.